# escaping "$" in sed in shell script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file where I have a bunch of server IPs ( either null or with some IP)

Scenario 1(File contents):

```
export Server1=""
export Server2=""
```

Scenario 2:

```
export Server1="10.10.10.1"
export Server2="10.10.10.2"
```

In both of the above cases I want to substitute the values for Server1 and Server2. I tried the following

```
Server1="11.11.11.1"
Server2="11.11.11.2"
sed -i -e 's/export Server1=""/export Server1=\$Server1/g' file.txt
sed -i -e 's/export Server2=""/export Server2=\$Server2/g' file.txt
```

For the first scenario the file gets replaced with the string instead of the value for vars

```
File content after substitution
export Server1=$Server1
export Server2=$Server2
```

I tried escaping the "$" character but it didnt work. What am I missing?

Comment: Variables are not expanded in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
Server1="111.111.111.111"
echo Server=Server1 | sed -e "s/Server1/$Server1/g"
```

Which gives as an output:

```
Server=111.111.111.111
```